# ERROR: subquery must return only one column

Tags: postgresql, join, select, subquery

I have two tables one is `Category` and other one is `Product`.

Table Description are

Category

- name
- description
- parent_id (self referencing key) (can be upto 3 levels)

Product

- name
- description
- type
- category_id (foreign key to Category table)

  I want to show all the categories on a single along with the associated products. So for getting associated categories I use the below query. I am able to do the left join at the self referential tables but I am not able to get list of product data, as this is a subquery and subquery would only return a single column.

  ```
      select                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                 cat1.id, ARRAY(select name, type, description from product where
                 product.category_id = cat1.id)
                 as category_1_products_data,

                 cat2.id, ARRAY(select name, type, description from product where
                 product.category_id = cat2.id)
                 as category_2_products_data,

                 cat3.id, ARRAY(select name, type, description from product where
                 product.category_id = cat3.id)
                 as category_3_products_data
      from       category cat1
      left join  category cat2
      on         cat2.parent_id = cat1.id
      left join  category cat3
      on         cat3.parent_id = cat2.id
      where      cat1.parent_id is null;
  ```

> ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
>    LINE 2:                        cat1.id, (select name, type, description from ...

Comment: Subselect returns 3 columns (`select name, type, description ...`) whereas ARRAY() wants one column. Think about something similar to `select ARRAY(name, type, description) ...`...

Comment: I would probably aggregate the product information into a JSONB array which makes it easier to retrieve and read the individual columns from the product table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All elements of an array must have the same type; when [constructing an array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) with a subquery, the simplest way to enforce this is to demand that the query returns exactly one column.

But you can make the subquery return a single column whose type is a [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) by using a [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
ARRAY(SELECT ROW(name, type, description) FROM ...)
```

Comment: I enhanced it with method `json_build_object` and now it looks like
`json_build_object('name', name, 'type', type, 'description', description)`